# Thread job assignment correctness

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

Suppose I have a bunch of worker threads and I'd like to avoid the time the threads take to determine who gets what job.

Suppose each thread has a number/ID associated with them. There is a job list. Each job in the queue has a ThreadID associated with it.

```
ThreadID
1          = Job Available
0          = Job Finished
> 1        = Active ==> ThreadID = ID of thread working on the job
```

For a thread to work on a job it scans the list and finds the first ThreadID = 1 and tries to take that job.

This way threads consume jobs. (Obviously they will sleep and need to be woken properly but ignore all that for now)

The problem is, that two threads may simultaneously attempt to work on the same job, which would be bad.

To solve this each thread simply has to assign it's thread ID to thread ID which will prevent other threads from working on the job *unless* the read of one happens before the write of thread ID.

```
ThreadID      Thread 11         Thread 12            ....
1             ThreadID == 1?                         Job available
                                ThreadID == 1?       Job available
11            ThreadID = 11                          Try to take job
12                              ThreadID == 12       Try to take job
              ThreadID == 11?                        Job was taken by another thread
                                ThreadID == 12?      (If no other competing threads then thread 12 got the job)
```

Not sure if the table makes sense but it shows two threads competing for the job. They both think they have the job but whichever thread actually has their number in the ThreadId got the job(it will be the last thread to write to ThreadID).

I believe such a scheme requires no locks and is safe? Is this correct?

Comment: This all depends on the memory model of the programming language you're using to implement this. However, this should be pretty straight-forward if you use *[compare and swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)*.

Comment: @DaoWen Yes, if CaS is available but I believe what I have said about compare write compare should work as well without locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your "compare-write-compare" method, as you describe it, isn't sufficient. See this case:

```
  Thread 0          Thread 1

reads <empty>
                  reads <empty> 
writes 0
reads 0
runs task
                  writes 1
                  reads 1
                  runs task
```

That interleaving would have both threads executing the same task. I might have missed something in your description, but if I understood your algorithm correctly then this should be a contradiction of its soundness.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I initially thought it would require one to compare multiple times(in a loop) which I think ultimately would still have such a flaw. I guess ultimately a CaS is required which would then allow it to work.

Comment: @user2541029 - Yes, you really need CaS. After all, that's why they've added it to all the modern architectures! You could also do something like [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm) where you have different threads write to different pieces of memory, but that's far less efficient than a CaS.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you have a collection of jobs and multiple threads to process the jobs you'll put the jobs in a thread-safe queue, either via locking or via more complicated non-blocking mechanisms, like `ConcurrentQueue<T>` in .NET 4.

Each thread takes a job from the queue and processes it.  You need some mechanism in place to job back in the queue if the thread fails to fully process it.

However, if you want to continue with your method of marking the job as being processed by a thread, it's simple enough to do it but you need to use locking to ensure only one thread modifies the job at a time.

Comment: This was the point of the last part of the question. By using the compare write compare there should be no need for locking, which I said, I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @user2541029, there are ways to set a value only if it is an existing value which will do what you want without locking.  Exactly how depends on what language you're using.  Which language are you using?